# Android action.MAIN and category.LAUNCHER function

Tags: android, manifest, intentfilter

We mention `android.intent.action.MAIN` and `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` as Intent filter of the launcher activity in the `Manifest.xml`. What is imp. of these two? What are their functionality?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

> category -- Gives additional
>   information about the action to
>   execute. For example,
>   CATEGORY_LAUNCHER means it should
>   appear in the Launcher as a top-level
>   application, while
>   CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE means it should
>   be included in a list of alternative
>   actions the user can perform on a
>   piece of data.

MAIN means that this activity is the entry point of the application, i.e. when you launch the application, this activity is created.

Comment: What will happen if I mention this intent-filter block twice?

Comment: Seems like the first one to be declared will be the main, but seems like undefined behavior for me. Interesting though...

Comment: Two activities with same intent filters, then the user is notified to select the correct activity. - dev_andriod

Comment: What does top-level application launcher mean?

Comment: Answering @Xegara it refers to the screen where your app icons appear and you launch one of them

Comment: but what about `shortcutManager`, you also use `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` for other activities to add as shortcuts to home screen, so which activity is main then?

Answer (score 21):

`MAIN` action is the main entry point of the application.

`LAUNCHER` category says that entry point should be listed in the application launcher.

Comment: but what about `shortcutManager`, you also use `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` for other activities to add as shortcuts to home screen, so which activity is main then?

Answer (score 2):

MAIN : will start the activity home.This activity will be the Home page of the application.

CATEGORY_LAUNCHER : The activity can be the initial activity of a task and is listed in the top-level application launcher.

Answer (score 1):

**MAIN:** the activity is the main entry point to the application i.e., the first activity to start when application starts

**LAUNCHER:** the activity will appear in top-level application launcher (where app icons appear and user can launch one of them).

Additionally, If two activites in an application have MAIN and LAUNCHER, then two icons will start appearing in top-level application launcher. Where each icon corresponds to each app activity